# Bootstrap Center Form & Logo like Responsive Search Engine

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-2

What would be the best way to have a logo and form in the center of the page while being responsive?

Currently, I have something like

```
<div class="container">
<img src="logo.jpg" class="logo img-responsive center-block">

<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group center-block">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

then I edited it slightly in the css;

```
.form-group { margin-top: 15px; width: 50% }
.logo { width: 300px; }
```

However, now the logo will not resize like the input box does.

Comment: make a fiddle to demonstrate

Comment: i think you need to choose between bootstrap 2 or 3 because the fluid container and the column tags changed

Answer (score 2):

now you'll need to change the col size for each media that you need xs sm md and lg but this would do the trick that you are looking for.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/250x300" class="logo img-responsive center-block" />
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group center-block">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" /> <span class="input-group-btn">
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

                        </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i assumed that you need a fluid container, the offset col would take , and for farther reading check [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/omarqa/7vAcU/)

Answer (score 0):

A fluid container does the trick, but a fixed container should be able to keep it center without taking all the screen span which is annoying on medium+ resolutions.

Also, media queries should keep .container within a specific width for responsiveness' sake.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/250x300" class="logo img-responsive center-block" />
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group center-block">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" /> <span class="input-group-btn">
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

                        </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```